# Event Listener on particular document Id, not on whole database

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

How can I continuously listen on particular document of a database in couchdb? If anything changes only in that document, then and only then I want to console that document, otherwise not. How can I achieve that?

my db entry in couchdb:

```
{
     "_id": "my-doc",
     "_rev": "13-7cf9b1373542d93da7b484774856429d",
     "awesome": "my-doc"
}
```

my code:

```
var
    util = require('util'),
    couchdb = require('felix-couchdb'),
    client = couchdb.createClient(5984, 'localhost'),
    db = client.db('lookup');

db.changesStream({id:"my-doc"}, function(err,success){
    if(!err){
        console.log(success)
    }
})
```

this code generates an error

```
    stream = new process.EventEmitter(),
             ^

TypeError: process.EventEmitter is not a constructor
    at exports.Db.Db.changesStream (/home/xyz/Projects/practice/node_modules/felix-couchdb/lib/couchdb.js:676:14)
```

other than I have tried using libraries like :- couchdb-api, couchdb-change-events..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To listen to a single document changes, you must supply `docs_ids=["$id"]` where $id is the id you want to track.
2. It seems like EventEmitter is not available. Perhaps you're trying to run nano in the browser?

You can use db.changes like this:

```
const nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
const db = nano.use('foo');

const req = db.changesAsStream({
    since: "now", feed: 'continuous', doc_ids: JSON.stringify(["my-doc", "doc_2"])
}).pipe(process.stdout);
```

I recommend using the db.follow API. It has more feature and it's more stable I think

```
const nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
const db = nano.use('foo');

const feed = db.follow({since: "now",filter:"_doc_ids",doc_ids:JSON.stringify(["my-doc","doc_2"])});
feed.on('change', (change) => {
  console.log("change: ", change);
});
feed.follow();
```

Comment: Hi alexis,
can you provide me with some example, cos now i using cradle library and this is my code..

`var feed = db.changes({include_docs:true,doc_ids:['$my-doc'],filters:{'_id':'my-doc'}});
feed.on('change',function (change) {
    console.log(change);
});`
this code is not working for me, and also i just latest updated entry while console but it is giving all the entries when restarting

Comment: @DharmikSoni added example

Comment: const feed = follow({db:"localhost:5984/lookup", since: "now",docs_ids:["my-doc"], include_docs:true}); feed.on('change', (change) => { console.log("change: ", change); }); feed.follow(); i have done this, although it is looking changes on whole database @Alexis Côté

Comment: Ok so I tested the example right now. Those are working properly

Comment: Thanks you. It helped me a lot :)